# MySQL: Get data from another table without duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a beginner in MySQL and I am having a bit of a problem. I have two tables. One of them is called `core` and has 200.000 entries and contains the column `messageid`. Another table is called `recipients`, has 1.200.000 entries and has the columns `recipientid`, `messageid` and `personid`.

I am creating a new column `personid` in the table `core` in order import the `personid` entries where the `messageid` in both columns are the same. I know that in the table `recipients`, there are multiple entries for several `messageid`'s, so I just want to return the first one. I am using the following sql query:

```
UPDATE core A
SET personid =
(SELECT personid
FROM recipients B
WHERE B.messageid = A.messageid)
```

I do not understand why, but it does not work. I works when I want to import data from other tables, but not this one. Ultimately, it just crashes my local php/mysql server.

Would you have any idea on how to do that?

Update:

Here is the result of SHOW INDEX FROM recipients.
The column name "recipientid" has a cardinality of 1356207 and the indextype is BTREE. The column name "messageid" has a cardinality of "NULL" and the indextype is BTREE.

When I run SHOW INDEX FROM core, the query runs successfully, but nothing is displayed. Does it mean there is a problem?

Comment: You are correct, I just updated it. I didn't paste the right code, sorry.

Comment: Sorry again, it should be OK now. Whenever I run this query, it just seems to be an endless loop until my server crashes. The same query works when I apply it to data from other tables.

Answer (score 0):

### Part 0 - Before you do anything else...

... you need to be able to perform queries on `core` without them either timing out or crashing the server. Based on your updated question, you're probably going to have to create some indexes on `core` to help speed up queries on it (otherwise the database has to scan the ***entire table*** to make sure it's doing the right thing).  At the very minimum, an index on `messageid` should help:

```
ALTER TABLE core ADD INDEX messageid_idx(messageid);
```

This index on messageid should help speed up any queries that operate upon that column, like the update query.

The rest of my answer will come in two parts.  First, the answer to your question, where you are sure you want to ignore multiple `personid`'s per `messageid` in `recipients`.

The second part of my answer contains additional queries that I would perform upfront to analyze the multiple `personid`'s to ascertain whether or not they really matter. Perhaps you're really sure that the multiple `personid`'s per `messageid` is no big deal, but then hopefully this will benefit others seeking answers to questions similar to yours.

### Part 1: Just any personid will do, thanks

For recipients with more than one `personid` per `messageid`, we'll just let the database engine decide which `personid` to use for update:

```
-- Update core personid with recipients personid where messageid matches
UPDATE
    core
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            messageid,
            personid
        FROM
            recipients
        GROUP BY
            messageid
    ) AS one_message_per_person USING (messageid)
SET
    core.personid = one_message_per_person.personid
```

Simple enough, right? Ok, let's move on.

### Part 2: Actually, I'm interested in those messages with multiple people. Which ones are they?

If you just want to know which `messageid`'s have multiple `personid`'s associated with them, you can query them with this:

```
-- Find messageids with more than one personid
SELECT
    messageid,
    personid,
    COUNT(DISTINCT personid) AS num_people_in_message
FROM
    recipients
GROUP BY
    messageid
HAVING
    num_people_in_message > 1
```

If you also want to see the individual `personid`'s associated with them, you can use the following query.  Note, there will be duplicate `messageid`'s, one for each indvidual `personid`:

```
-- Show the messageid and personid of the messages with multiple people
    SELECT
    messageid,
    personid
FROM
    recipients
WHERE
    messageid IN (
        SELECT
            messageid
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    messageid,
                    personid,
                    COUNT(DISTINCT personid) AS num_people_in_message
                FROM
                    recipients
                GROUP BY
                    messageid
                HAVING
                    num_people_in_message > 1
            ) AS messages_with_multiple_people
    )
GROUP BY
    messageid, personid
```

Did I understand your question correctly and provide the answer you needed? I hope so.  Many thanks to [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38738/5) for helping me make sure those queries would actually work for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a great answer! I am impressed! However, when I run the first query, it still seems to be not working. Basically, it goes on for 10 minutes until my local server shuts down, and when I turn it back on, no data has been modified. Do you think it my be because I have 1 million rows in my "recipients" table?

Comment: That might be the case.  I wonder what indexes you have on these tables.  Could you update your question to show the results of running `SHOW INDEX FROM core` and `SHOW INDEX FROM recipients`?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can use select and update in one query for MySQL
my advice would be to use procedures to achieve the same